Is this transaction code with using async valid or is it bad practice?
I found a lot of code working with transaction in an app in which I do a code review.
A lot of times there is no rollback-handling explicit and I first thought, that the rollback will never made and the transaction is therefore never closed.
I found out, after a bit research, that his is wrong and with EF Core a "using" in front of a BeginTransaction causes the transaction to be rollbacked when not commited at the end of the using.
So I found e.g. this:
  using var transaction = _dbContext.Database.CurrentTransaction
        ?? await _dbContext.Database.BeginTransactionAsync(cancellationToken);

Is this all in all good code or bad practice?

Opinion: When the DB already is in transaction how will I know that it is save to dispose it after my code here?

This following:
using var transaction = _dbContext.Database.CurrentTransaction
        ?? await _dbContext.Database.BeginTransactionAsync(cancellationToken);

is a bad practice in quite a lot of cases. As a rule of thumb you should not dispose resources you "don't own". In this case code assumes that someone could open the transaction before and if it will be closed (after using finishes) it will be closed for the one who opened it earlier. Hence consider the scenario:
using var transaction = await _dbContext.Database.BeginTransactionAsync(cancellationToken);

SomeMethodUsingCurrentTranOrCreatingNew(); // the method containing the first snippet

// ...

transaction.Commit();

Will result in exception thrown on the commit.
While the exception highly likely will be caught quite easily (and fixed, for example incorporating approach similar to the leaveOpen in the StreamWriter API) I would argue that the code shows that there is something wrong happening from architecture/design point of view but it is hard to tell without seeing the whole codebase.
